# Firebase: how take a diff of mismatched images and delete the ones from Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, gsutil

My firebase database saves the images with the name:URL and a UUID and uploads it to storage...

How can I use gsutil or any other method to take a diff of mismatched images and delete the ones from Storage? It would really be helpful if you could provide me with an example.

Please find the snapshot of the schema.

[json schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpepS.png)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include more information on the data structure your use? Right now it's impossible to give a concrete answer. It also seems unlikely that `gsutil` alone is enough to accomplish this. Seeing what you've already tried would go a long way towards helping too.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have just added the image for schema. Also, I have gone so far and got the list of images in the store like this : gsutil ls gs://firebasestorage.url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to delete the images from Cloud Storage that no longer have a reference to them in the Firebase Database.

That's a 3 step process:

1. Create a list of all the images on Cloud Storage. The easiest way to do this programmatically in JavaScript is through the [Node.js SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/Bucket#getFiles) or the [HTTP JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list).
2. Create a list of all image URLs from the database, through its [Node.js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-types).
3. Loop through the list of files from Cloud Storage. If the URL for a file does not exist in the list of URLs from the database, that file is orphaned and you can delete it.